# Nginx mamp pro5 migration home page works all other do not

Tags: migration, nginx

Home page works all other pages do not, receive 404.

figured this out from other post outside of stack.

put this in the try files under the Nginx tab.
$uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

Answer (score 0):

place this in the nginx tab of mamp pro 
under the try files:

```
$uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?